# how to select rows with multiple where conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

Not sure if the title made sense.

But this what I need, I am bad at sql:

I have table with the following data

```
ID| Value
------ | ------
1| A
1| B
1| C
1| D
2| A
2| B
2| C
```

I need O/P as

```
2 A
2 B
2 C
```

Using Select id where value in (A,B,C) and Not in (D)
is giving me o/p as

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
2 A
2 B
2 C
```

Need to select Id's having A,B,C but not D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rows which has one or more value in A, B, C, but not D:

```
select *
from your_table
where value in ('A', 'B', 'C')
    and id not in (
        select id
        from your_table
        where value = 'D'
        );
```

If you want that all the three values A, B, C must be present for that id and but not D.

```
select id,
    value
from (
    select t.*,
        count(distinct value) over (partition by id) n
    from your_table t
    where value in ('A', 'B', 'C')
        and id not in (
            select id
            from your_table
            where value = 'D'
            )
    )
where n = 3;
```

If you want to get rows having only A, B, C (and all of them present) then use :

```
select id,
    value
from (
    select t.*,
        count(case 
                when value not in ('A', 'B', 'C')
                    then 1
                end) over (partition by id) n,
        count(distinct case 
                when value in ('A', 'B', 'C')
                    then value
                end) over (partition by id) n2
    from your_table t
    )
where n = 0
    and n2 = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you :) The second solution is what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation in a `HAVING` clause to filter across rows for each `id`:

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

This will show you which `id` values meet your criteria, and if you need you can put this in a subquery and join it to your table to get all the rows for that `id`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 a
JOIN (    SELECT id
          FROM table1
          GROUP BY id
          HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
             AND MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
             AND MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
             AND MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
    ) b
ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understood that to find the count of `Value` column where the values are `A, B, C` but `Value` not equal to `D`. Then simply put those 3 value in `IN` operator. I will retrieve the result set without `D`.

**Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(Value) count, Value
FROM your_table_name
WHERE Value in ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY Value;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id, value 
from my_table
where value in ('A','B','C')
and id = 2
```